# VB.net timer tick event question

Tags: vb.net, loops, timer

I wrote the following code to build a basic game that makes two cars race (randomgenerator) and let the user pick their bets on the end results.  I've gone terribly wrong somewhere in that my cars only race halfway then get stuck behind the start line and the programme keeps repeating the beeping and the messsagebox.show and adding results to the 'incorrect' box.  I've spent the last three days trying to figure out where I've gone wrong and I'm just missing it.  Thank you for taking the time to look at this.  I really appreciate any advice.

The only way to terminate the application is to hit 'stop debugging'.

[image: Screen shot of application]

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Public Class MainForm

    Private Sub exitButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles exitButton.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub


    Private Sub MainForm_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'fills the list box with items, then selects the first item
        resultListBox.Items.Add("No guess")
        resultListBox.Items.Add("Tie")
        resultListBox.Items.Add("Red Car wins")
        resultListBox.Items.Add("White car wins")
        resultListBox.SelectedIndex = 0
    End Sub

    Private Sub startButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles startButton.Click
        raceTimer.Enabled = True

    End Sub

    Private Sub raceTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles raceTimer.Tick
        ' moves two cars from a starting line to a finish line on the form
        ' displays a message indicating the race results
        ' calculates and displays the number of times the user selects the
        ' correct race result from the resultlistbox, and the number
        ' of times the user selects an incorrect race result

        Dim randomgenerator As New Random
        Dim whitenewlocation As Integer
        Dim rednewlocation As Integer
        Dim raceresult As String
        Dim userchoice As String
        Dim finishline As Integer = finishTextBox.Left + 1
        Static numbercorrect As Integer
        Static numberincorrect As Integer

        ' save the user's list box selection, then disable the list box
        userchoice = resultListBox.SelectedItem.ToString
        resultListBox.Enabled = False

        'calculate the new location of each picture box's right border
        ' don't allow the right border to go beyond the finish line
        whitenewlocation = whitePictureBox.Right + randomgenerator.Next(0, 11)
        If whitenewlocation > finishline Then
            whitenewlocation = finishline
        End If
        rednewlocation = redPictureBox.Right + randomgenerator.Next(0, 11)
        If rednewlocation > finishline Then
            rednewlocation = finishline
        End If

        'move each picture box toward the finish line
        whitePictureBox.SetBounds(whitenewlocation - whitePictureBox.Width, 0, 0, 0, BoundsSpecified.X)
        redPictureBox.SetBounds(rednewlocation - redPictureBox.Width, 0, 0, 0, BoundsSpecified.X)

        'the following selection structure is processed only when at least
        ' one of the picture boxes is at the finish line
        If whitePictureBox.Right = finishline _
            OrElse redPictureBox.Right = finishline Then
            'disable the timer
            raceTimer.Enabled = False
        End If

        'sound a beep to indicate the end of the race
        For x As Integer = 1 To 5
            Console.Beep(100, 100)
        Next x

        'store the result of the race in a variable
        If whitenewlocation = rednewlocation Then
            raceresult = "Tie"
        ElseIf whitenewlocation > rednewlocation Then
            raceresult = "White car wins"
        Else
            raceresult = "red car wins"
        End If

        'display the race results
        MessageBox.Show("Race Over!" & ControlChars.NewLine & raceresult, _
        "Car Race", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        'move the picture boxes back to the starting line
        whitePictureBox.SetBounds(12, 0, 0, 0, BoundsSpecified.X)
        redPictureBox.SetBounds(12, 0, 0, 0, BoundsSpecified.X)


        'if the user did not want to guess the race results, then
        'don't update or display the counter values; otherwise,
        'compare the race results to the user's selection and update
        ' the appropriate counter, then display both counter values
        If userchoice <> "no guess" Then
            If raceresult = userchoice Then
                numbercorrect = numbercorrect + 1
            Else
                numberincorrect = numberincorrect + 1
            End If
            correctLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(numbercorrect)
            incorrectLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(numberincorrect)
        End If

        'enable the list box
        resultListBox.Enabled = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timer is doing everything at every tick. The code that handle the end of the race is processed every tick of the timer. It should be enclosed in the if-logic that handles the end of the race.

Allmost eveything after the comment "sound a beep to indicate the end of the race" should be inside the check for end of race:

```
If whitePictureBox.Right = finishline  OrElse redPictureBox.Right = finishline Then
    'put all logic of the "ending" of the race here
end if
```

So this code will work as you expected:

```
Private Sub raceTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RaceTimer.Tick
    ' moves two cars from a starting line to a finish line on the form
    ' displays a message indicating the race results
    ' calculates and displays the number of times the user selects the
    ' correct race result from the resultlistbox, and the number
    ' of times the user selects an incorrect race result

    Dim randomgenerator As New Random
    Dim whitenewlocation As Integer
    Dim rednewlocation As Integer
    Dim raceresult As String
    Dim userchoice As String
    Dim finishline As Integer = finishTextBox.Left + 1
    Static numbercorrect As Integer
    Static numberincorrect As Integer

    ' save the user's list box selection, then disable the list box
    userchoice = resultListBox.SelectedItem.ToString
    resultListBox.Enabled = False

    'calculate the new location of each picture box's right border
    ' don't allow the right border to go beyond the finish line
    whitenewlocation = whitePictureBox.Right + randomgenerator.Next(0, 11)
    If whitenewlocation > finishline Then
        whitenewlocation = finishline
    End If
    rednewlocation = redPictureBox.Right + randomgenerator.Next(0, 11)
    If rednewlocation > finishline Then
        rednewlocation = finishline
    End If

    'move each picture box toward the finish line
    whitePictureBox.SetBounds(whitenewlocation - whitePictureBox.Width, 0, 0, 0, BoundsSpecified.X)
    redPictureBox.SetBounds(rednewlocation - redPictureBox.Width, 0, 0, 0, BoundsSpecified.X)

    'the following selection structure is processed only when at least
    ' one of the picture boxes is at the finish line
    If whitePictureBox.Right = finishline _
        OrElse redPictureBox.Right = finishline Then
        'disable the timer
        RaceTimer.Enabled = False
        'sound a beep to indicate the end of the race
        For x As Integer = 1 To 5
            Console.Beep(100, 100)
        Next x

        'store the result of the race in a variable
        If whitenewlocation = rednewlocation Then
            raceresult = "Tie"
        ElseIf whitenewlocation > rednewlocation Then
            raceresult = "White car wins"
        Else
            raceresult = "red car wins"
        End If

        'display the race results
        MessageBox.Show("Race Over!" & ControlChars.NewLine & raceresult, _
        "Car Race", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        'move the picture boxes back to the starting line
        whitepicturebox.SetBounds(12, 0, 0, 0, BoundsSpecified.X)
        redpicturebox.SetBounds(12, 0, 0, 0, BoundsSpecified.X)


        'if the user did not want to guess the race results, then
        'don't update or display the counter values; otherwise,
        'compare the race results to the user's selection and update
        ' the appropriate counter, then display both counter values
        If userchoice <> "no guess" Then
            If raceresult = userchoice Then
                numbercorrect = numbercorrect + 1
            Else
                numberincorrect = numberincorrect + 1
            End If
            correctlabel.Text = Convert.ToString(numbercorrect)
            incorrectlabel.Text = Convert.ToString(numberincorrect)
        End If

        'enable the list box
        Resultlistbox.Enabled = True
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: No way!  Thank you so much.  I was concentrating so much on logic erros that I completely overlooked the decision constructs!  This was a huge learning curve for me. Thanks so much Stefan!